# Getting spring oauth2 user info data

Tags: kotlin, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have an oauth2 server and client. In client I configured ClientRegistrationRepository:

```
@Bean
@Conditional(SsoCondition::class)
open fun clientRegistrationRepository(): ClientRegistrationRepository {
    val test = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(registrationId)
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
            .authorizationUri(authorizeUri)
            .tokenUri(tokenUri)
            .userInfoUri(userInfoUri)
            .scope("read", "write")
            .userNameAttributeName(userNameAttribute)
            .build()

    return InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(test)
}
```

This works fine and authorization is performed. 
The problem is in userInfoUri. This uri is invoked and needed server method is performed. I see the user data and that method return this data.
The method for authorizeUri is:

```
@GetMapping("/api/user/me")
fun getUserInfo(response: HttpServletResponse, request: HttpServletRequest, principal: Principal): HashMap<String, Any?> {
    val authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication
    val userData = HashMap<String, Any?>()
    userData[OUTER_ID] = principal.name
    val ssoUser = authentication.userAuthentication.principal.attributes

    // getting data from ssoUser to userData
    ...

    return userData
}
```

And so the question is: where or how can I get this data in the client application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how right this solution, but I got the user data like this:

1. Creating custom implementation of OAuth2AuthorizedClientService interface:

```
class CustomOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(private val clientRegistrationRepository: ClientRegistrationRepository) : OAuth2AuthorizedClientService {
    private val principalData = ConcurrentHashMap<String, Authentication>()
    ...
    override fun saveAuthorizedClient(authorizedClient: OAuth2AuthorizedClient, principal: Authentication) {
        ...
        val key = ... // create some key
        principalData[key] = principal
    }
    ...
    fun getPrincipal(key: String): Authentication? {
        return authorizedClientsPrincipal[key]
    }
}
```

2. Creating bean for CustomOAuth2AuthorizedClientService:

```
@Bean
open fun authorizedClientService(): OAuth2AuthorizedClientService {
    return CustomOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository())
}
```

where clientRegistrationRepository() is a ClientRegistrationRepository bean.

3. In the code get user data from CustomOAuth2AuthorizedClientService bean:

```
@Autowired
private var oAuth2AuthorizedClientService: OAuth2AuthorizedClientService
...
fun test() {
 val userData = (oAuth2AuthorizedClientService as CustomOAuth2AuthorizedClientService).getPrincipal(key)
}
```